# Creating AWS SSM Document to run Powershell commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, yaml, aws-ssm

Im trying to make an SSM Document that runs the following Powershell script:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\temp
$checkupdatesscript = "`$UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session"
$checkupdatesscript | Out-File C:\temp\checkwindowsupdates.ps1
Add-Content -Path C:\temp\checkwindowsupdates.ps1 -Value "`$UpdateSearcher = `$UpdateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()"
Add-Content -Path C:\temp\checkwindowsupdates.ps1 -Value "`$Updates = @(`$UpdateSearcher.Search(`"IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0`").Updates)"
Add-Content -Path C:\temp\checkwindowsupdates.ps1 -Value "`$Updates | Select-Object Title > C:\temp\windowsupdates.txt" 
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument "C:\temp\checkwindowsupdates.ps1"
$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date) -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5)
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "Check Windows Updates" -Description "checks for any outstanding windows updates every 5 minutes"
```

I have created the following SSM Document in YAML:

```
---
schemaVersion: "2.2"
description: "Creates script and scheduled task to check for any outstanding windows updates every 5 minutes"
mainSteps:
- action: "aws:runPowerShellScript"
  name: "RunCommands"
  inputs:
    runCommand:
      - "New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\temp"
      - "$checkupdatesscript = \"`$UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session\""
      - "$checkupdatesscript | Out-File C:\temp\checkwindowsupdates.ps1"
      - "Add-Content -Path C:\temp\checkwindowsupdates.ps1 -Value \"`$UpdateSearcher = `$UpdateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()\""
      - "Add-Content -Path C:\temp\checkwindowsupdates.ps1 -Value \"`$Updates = @(`$UpdateSearcher.Search(`\"IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0`\").Updates)\""
      - "Add-Content -Path C:\temp\checkwindowsupdates.ps1 -Value \"`$Updates | Select-Object Title > C:\temp\windowsupdates.txt\""
      - "$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute \"Powershell.exe\" -Argument \"C:\temp\checkwindowsupdates.ps1\""
      - "$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date) -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5)"
      - "Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName \"Check Windows Updates\" -Description \"checks for any outstanding windows updates every 5 minutes\""
```

But am receiving an error when attempting to create the document. The error is "InvalidDocumentContent: null"

I am assuming I have messed up the YAML but can't seem to figure out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue did lie within the YAML. I had not escaped the backslashes in the file paths. The correct yaml should look like this:

```html
---
schemaVersion: "2.2"
description: "Creates script and scheduled task to check for any outstanding windows updates every 5 minutes"
mainSteps:
- action: "aws:runPowerShellScript"
  name: "RunCommands"
  inputs:
    runCommand:
      - "New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\\temp"
      - "$checkupdatesscript = \"`$UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session\""
      - "$checkupdatesscript | Out-File C:\\temp\\checkwindowsupdates.ps1"
      - "Add-Content -Path C:\\temp\\checkwindowsupdates.ps1 -Value \"`$UpdateSearcher = `$UpdateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()\""
      - "Add-Content -Path C:\\temp\\checkwindowsupdates.ps1 -Value \"`$Updates = @(`$UpdateSearcher.Search(`\"IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0`\").Updates)\""
      - "Add-Content -Path C:\\temp\\checkwindowsupdates.ps1 -Value \"`$Updates | Select-Object Title > C:\\temp\\windowsupdates.txt\""
      - "$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute \"Powershell.exe\" -Argument \"C:\\temp\\checkwindowsupdates.ps1\""
      - "$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date) -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5)"
      - "Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName \"Check Windows Updates\" -Description \"checks for any outstanding windows updates every 5 minutes\""
```